# How call a function from plug-in relative file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to develop with wordpress but i  stuck, that i cannot call function from my plug-in relative .php file

> my-plugin-folder/my-plugin-name.php
>   my-plugin-folder/includes/idv_unsubscribe.php

so in my my-plugin-name.php i write:

```
function adminSettingsMenu(){
  add_menu_page(' Headlines', ' Headlines', 'idv_letters', 'letter-settings', 'pre_made_letter');
  add_submenu_page('letter-settings', 'Unsubscribe', 'Unsubscribe', 'idv_letters', 'unsubscribe-settings', 'callUnsubscribe');
}
```

later in my-plugin-name.php:

```
function callUnsubscribe(){
  include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/idv_unsubscribe.php';
}
```

in idv_unsubscribe.php i am trying to call a function but it is not working

```
function my_enqueue() {
  exit("asd");
}
```

if a do this outside a function it exit("123"), but not a exit("asd"):

```
function my_enqueue() {
  exit("asd");
}
exit("123");
```

i tried to use add_action, but it is not working, what should i do?

Comment: Where did u call my_enqueue()?

Comment: i think nowhere, o don't know how and where to call it :(

Comment: If it's defined in idv_unsubscribe.php, then you may call it anytime after it is included.

Comment: damn me, again i am looking hard solution, for simple question :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply defining a function won't call it. You need to explicitly call it, or add it to an action hook:

```
function my_enqueue() {
  exit("asd");
}
my_enqueue();
```

My guess is that you're going to want to add it to an action hook, rather than calling it as I have done above.